# Why was this audit not "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed this audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10823414

It is not obviously spammy etc., however it asks what looks like a homework question, offers no code, nor does it tag or mention a language in which the author is attempting to write code. In other words, it's a "please write code for me" request. I flagged it as "too broad." This is how I always flag such questions.

What is the expectation in this case? My impression has been that questions where there is no effort shown, and which have these odd contrived problems that smell like homework problems, are normally considered either too broad, or close due to lack of a MCVE.

Before someone suggests I should have seen the user was not low-rep or that the question has many votes, I tend to ignore those things because I suspect the audit system lies about them to see if you're reading the text critically vs. simply assuming votes/rep give a free pass to "Looks OK."

Or is it the case that we only hold low-rep users to that standard? I see that even though no effort has been shown, people still upvoted it, still wrote code and posted answers, and nobody seems to be challenging the question in comments like is usually seen when there's no MCVE and so on. If this was from a < 30 rep user, same text, I'd be very surprised if it was not close-voted and full of comments accusing the OP of posting homework.

Comment: "Before someone suggests I should have seen the user was not low-rep or that the question has many votes, I tend to ignore those things" - because the actual score and the user is masked until you complete the audit :)

Comment: There is an upvoted comment asking what language and for the OP to post their code. Nobody voted to close though, since at least the problem itself is clear (I assume), so it's just not a good audit question. Now that it does have a vote to close, it shouldn't be used as an audit again.

Comment: Occassionally, I come across a really bad question asked by a user whose rep is in the 5-10K range. Checking the profile reveals that they have hundreds of questions, many of which are also crap, but somehow they managed to get enough upvotes on enough questions to avoid a ban. I guess they are an edge-case. This one, however, almost seems like vote fraud. Like his entire class upvoted his question because he "helped" everybody do their assignment.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Do you know if that is still the case if the CV ages away?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know if that's the case or not.

Comment: I'm not sure if the bounties are shown in the timeline or not now, but if not then that could be a reason why it didn't receive close votes, though I'm not sure why it didn't receive any downvotes

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) so OP is not asking for any code. OP is asking for a description of steps required to solve a general problem. No code but an abstract solution.

So the lack of a language tag is actually good. Had there been a language tag, it would have been a "write my code" question and should have been closed on that ground. But since there is no language tag, it is fine - so far.

However, the next question is:

> Is the question really about an algorithm?

It can be difficult to decide when something is an algorithm and when it isn't.

Had the question asked about an algorithm for searching, sorting, etc. the question would be fine to me.

But the relative location of second, minute, hour on a clock doesn't seem a general interesting algorithm to me - it seems more like home work - so I would say `off topic`.

In any case I find it too hard that you failed the audit because you said `too broad`.

Comment: `it would have been a "write my code" question and should have been closed on that ground`...... um, could you point me to the write my code for me close reason?